# Trigger workflow on Github push - Pipeline plugin - Multibranch configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

We are using the pipeline plugin with multibranch configuration for our CD. 
We have checked in the Jenkinsfile which works off git.

```
git url: "$url",credentialsId:'$credentials'
```

The job works fine, but does not auto trigger when a change is pushed to github. 
I have set up the GIT web hooks correctly.

Interestingly, when I go into a branch of the multibranch job and I click "View Configuration", I see that the "Build when a change is pushed to Github" is unchecked. There is no way to check it since I can not modify the configuration of the job (since it takes from parent) and the same option is not there in parent.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What GH webhook event have you registered? `push` event would be the only required. Is your Jenkins visible from internet? Is GH webhook status showing return values from Jenkins webhook receiver?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this without polling?

Answer (score 7):

For declarative pipelines try:

```
pipeline {
    ...
    triggers {
        githubPush()
    }
    ...
}
```

For me this enables the checkbox "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling", but polling is not actually required. This requires the GitHub plugin.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @trebor not that I can find. I can't remember where I got this from now.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to check the checkbox "Build when a change is pushed to Github".

This line did the trick:

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'GitHubPushTrigger'], pollSCM('H/15 * * * *')])])
```

I think the polling is needed to make it work. Would be nice if no polling is needed.

Here's a `Jenkinsfile` example with this implemented:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node ('master'){
    stage('Build and Test') {
        properties([pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'GitHubPushTrigger'], pollSCM('H/15 * * * *')])])
        checkout scm
        env.PATH = "${tool 'Maven 3'}/bin:${env.PATH}"
        sh 'mvn clean package'
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to achieve the same thing for bitbucket?

Comment: @Lake - This change should work for BitBucket: `properties([pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'BitBucketTrigger'], pollSCM('H/15 * * * *')])])`

Answer (score 2):

For declarative pipelines, try this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        pollSCM('') //Empty quotes tells it to build on a push
    }
}
```

Comment: this needs to setup github hook first?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Stash for example you can register a Post-Receive WebHook where you have to insert your URL form Jenkins like : http://jenkinsHost:9090/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@gitHost:1234/test.git

In your jenkins Job you have to set at least the Build trigger "Poll SCM".
And set a polling time of e.g 5 mins.
This enables also the automatic branch indexing for your multibranch project configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Resorting to polling adds latency - time that it takes for a build to start and hence finish giving back a result.

It seemed to me that the basic plugins have a low level of abstraction, so I switched to the [Github Organization Folder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Organization+Folder+Plugin) plugin, which depends on all of them and sets up an organization hook for triggering builds branches and/or pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, I would like to emphasize that I had no previous experience with Jenkins so far, so there might be a bunch of better solutions out there.

What I wanted to achieve in a nutshell:

- After every push made to a Bitbucket repo(test2), on every branch,
  pull and build another Bitbucket repo(test1), from an identical
  branch name and right after that, build test2 using test1 as a
  dependency.

How I managed to achieve that?

- I started a new job with type 'Multibranch Pipeline'
- I added the following Jenkinsfile to test2:

```js
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                dir('test1') {
                    git branch: BRANCH_NAME, url: 'git@bitbucket.org:user/test1.git', credentialsId: 'credentials_id'
                }
                sh('build_process')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- I come across the issue that you can't set up a Bitbucket hook for pipelines
- I added Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin to Jenkins
- I selected Bitbucket at 'Branch Sources' when setting up the job
- I added credentials and put a checkmark to Auto-register webhook
- Under 'Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers' I put a checkmark to Periodically if not otherwise run, with an interval of 1 min
- I added a webhook to my Bitbucket repo
- I updated all my plugins, restarted Jenkins and it's ready to go

Other plugins I have installed: Bitbucket Plugin, Pipeline plugin. Hope this helps for somebody, I did manage to solve it this way after hours of struggling without the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin.

Answer (score -3):

```
node{
stage('Build and Test') {
    properties([pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'GitHubPushTrigger'], pollSCM('* * * * *')])])
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx[your credentails Id]', url: 'https://github.com/git']]])
    echo 'Build and Test has been done'
}
```

}