# Jenkins Pipeline for GitHub projects

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins and wanna add GitHub projects to it. I have a way which works fine but it’s not what I want.
Currently I'm using Multibranch Pipeline because this is the only way I found to combine Pipeline (and using the Jenkinsfile in my repo) and Git (for using my GitHub repo as source).

If I try to only use pipeline, there is no way to add a Git source. If I use "Free Style", there is no way to say "hey use the Jenkinsfile in the repo" or just to use pipeline. Maybe there is but I don’t know how.

I don’t want to use Multibranch Pipeline, I wanna use something where I only have one project which is build everytime I push something. If I need another plugin, please let me know. I'm really completely new to Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy. You use the pipeline and where you should type in your script, you change it to use scm. Then you can add your Git and it’s what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal Pipeline Job (not a multibranch one)

[image]

Define where your Jenkinsfile (Pipeline) is coming from in the Configure section of YourBuildJob

[image]

Install the **GitHub Integration Plugin** to enable advanced GitHub Build triggering.

In your declarative pipeline define a 'triggers' section:

```
pipeline {
    ...
    triggers {
        githubPush()
    }
    ...
}
```

Which enables the checkbox "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling", but polling is not actually required.

This should work.

This links can be also helpful:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

[Trigger workflow on Github push - Pipeline plugin - Multibranch configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781817/trigger-workflow-on-github-push-pipeline-plugin-multibranch-configuration)