# How can I re-run PR build in Jenkins multibranch pipeline when base branch updated?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I create a Jenkins job with multibranch pipeline, and triggered by `develop` and `PR-*` branches.

By setting strategy to "All branches" and "Discover pull requests from origin" to "Merging the pull request with the current target branch revision", I can build when

- new commit in `develop` branch, develop branch pipeline triggered.
- PR open (`develop` <- `feature/aaa`), PR build with code which merged develop and `feature/aaa` branch
- new commit in `feature/aaa` branch, PR build with code with merged `develop` and new `feature/aaa` branch

But when new commit in `develop`, there is no trigger in opened pull request (which merge target is `develop`)'s pipeline.

I want to re-build in `PR-123` when develop branch updated.

How can I triggering the Pull Request job when target branch updated?

Any idea how to do or if it's actually possible?

Comment: Rebase the pull request?

Comment: when target brance(develop) update, all PR(even if made by other people) should be rebuild. I can't rebase all PR source branches.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60006988/1437758 might help.

There is an additional approach:

```
triggers {
    upstream env.BRANCH_NAME != 'develop' ? 'develop' : ''
}
```

This will set up a trigger between the upstream (develop) and downstream builds (PR-*)